# Javascript feature detect CMYK images

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, feature-detection, cmyk

It is well known that ie8 doesn't support cmyk jpg images, it just doesn't render them at all :-(

here is one post about it http://www.plaveb.com/blog/cmyk-images-not-displayed-in-internet-explorer, there are countless others.

My question:
Is there a a way to feature detect from javascript, similar to how modernizr works, to check if a browser supports cmyk jpg images?

I can put a hack in my javascript to change behaviour for ie8 to use a rgb jpg but I would like the hack to be a little more robust.

Thanks,

Comment: Why not just *always* use RGB images? You're viewing the website on a screen, right? If you're really fussed about printing, you could swap out your images for CMYK images in a print stylesheet (or something similar)...

Comment: You using any server-side languages, they all should have features to do this. ASP.NET - the Bitmap API and PHP the getImageSize should have the number of channels.

Comment: @ahren - when you say always use RBG images, is that because the browser wont show cmyk colors anyway?  or is there some other reason?

Comment: @Dane: I may not have posed my question well enough, you are right its easy to detect within the image if it is rgb or cmyk, what i was after was a way to check if the browser supports rending of cmyk images.

Comment: Can you not use a directive to check if it's IE 8 or below, that should be the only one as far as I know, that doesn't support CMYK? (sorry misread the question)

Comment: @Dane: yeah that's the best solution i could find as well.

Comment: @rabs - because screen's display their pixels in RGB

Comment: @ahren: thanks for your info there, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this: (with jQuery of course their are HTML directives)

```
if ($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) <= 8) {
  alert('IE8 or below'); 
} else {
  alert('Non IE8');
}
```

and HTML ->

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    ie = 8;
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Ok here is some Javascript, this works with RGBA, so it should with CMYK, you could test:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    var IS_CMYK_SUPPORTED = (function(){
        var value = 'cmyk(1%,1%,1%,0.5%)',
        el = document.createElement('p'),
        result = false;
        try {
            el.style.color = value;
            result = /^cmyk/.test(el.style.color);
        } catch(e) { }
        el = null;
        return result;
    })();
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad='alert("IS CMYK Supported:" + IS_CMYK_SUPPORTED)'>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would like to see if there is any other way to do it without just checking for ie8

Comment: Browser sniffing is deeply flawed, conditional comments are likely the best way since you can also use them to insert an alternative style sheet to provide supported images instead.

Comment: This looks like it works :) On my Mac ran it against Chrome which failed to create a 'fake' color for my html element, and in Safari it returned to true :)